# Cannot call determinedVisibility() never saw a connection for the pid

Tags: android

I have a FrameLayout with a DrawerLayout inside that contains a RelativeLayout and a ExpandableListView. The RelativeLayout contains two views: FrameLayout and another RelativeLayout.

This is what happens: I only show one of those two views at the same time and everything works fine the fist time I execute the activity, but when I run it for the second time I can not change my view.

I do not get any error while trying to change views visibility (I hide one and show the other). But I get this error when starting the activity:

11-12 20:04:18.577: W/cr.BindingManager(9100): **Cannot call determinedVisibility()** - never saw a connection for the pid: 9100

I've seen other solutions such us:
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

But I do not have a webview (although I am using wikitude in one of the views, so It could be using a webview...).

Any idea??

Thank you very much in advance.